# Slider personalizado jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

estoy realizando un proyecto en que que tengo que hacer un slider y al momento que cambie el slider cambie la informacion de un div, aqui el ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento que cambia el slider izquierdo cambia la imagen del lado derecho, yo tengo este codigo ya que esta pagina de la imagen la realice yo pero esta en reactJS y ahora quiero realizar lo mismo pero con jquery y no encuentro nungun ejemplo de algo asi, si me pudieron ayudar a pasarme ejemplos o algun codigo que ustedes tengan ya seria mucha ayuda

Comment: [este slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) puede serte de ayuda

Comment: ahorita lo reviso amigo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

[Aquí tienes](https://devexus.net/articles/how-to-create-simple-slider-with-jquery/) un ejemplo bastante interesante.

Podrás ver ejemplo de código tanto para la vista, la generación del código en jQuery y la guía de estilos, además de permitirte bajar el código para que hagas pruebas en local.

De todos modos, en este ejemplo el slider cambia de slides de forma automática cada X segundos, pero el proceso es el mismo

Comment: ok ahorita lo reviso, muchas gracias